# JqGrid Specifying the Column Label using colNames vs using label property from colNames

Tags: jqgrid

I have been using jqGrid for a while And I am just wondering what the difference is between using colNames to specify the Label as shown

```js
colNames:['Actions','Inv No'],
colModel [
    {name:'act',index:'act',width:55,align:'center'},
    {name:'inv',width:100,align:'left'}
]
```

OR using the Label property of colModel as shown below

```js
colModel [
    {label:'Actions', name:'act',index:'act',width:55,align:'center'},
    {label:'Inv No', name:'inv',width:100,align:'left'}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no differences in both declarations. The usage of `colNames` is a little shorter because one provides the same information without including the text `label:` before every text of the column header. On the other side including `label:` and skipping `colNames` have some small practical advantages. Everybody who modified old code had made an error: one removed (commented) one column in `colModel`, but one forget to remove (to comment) the corresponding item in `colNames`.

I find important to understand how the `label` information be used. Look at [the code fragment](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.12.1/js/grid.base.js#L4636-L4640):

```js
if (p.colNames.length === 0) {
    for (iCol = 0; iCol < p.colModel.length; iCol++) {
        p.colNames[iCol] = p.colModel[iCol].label !== undefined ?
                p.colModel[iCol].label :
                p.colModel[iCol].name;
    }
}
```

You can see that jqGrid tests whether `colNames` is specified. If the `colNames` is empty array (it's default value of `colNames`), then the `colNames` array will be filled with information from `label` or `name` property.

It's all. I personally fine the code which uses `label` instead of `colNames` more readable.

One additional small remark I have to include to be more exactly. If **both** `colNames` and `label` are specified, then jqGrid uses `colNames` for column headers, but the `label` will be used as the label in [the Searching Dialog](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching) (see the text "Inv No" in the searching dialog).

Comment: Thanks Oleg for the explanation and well formed answer.

Answer (score 1):

`colNames` and `label` does the same thing; assign column name on header layer.

Only difference that I could read into is `colNames` takes priority over `label`. if both are defined `colNames` values are shown as header.

`label` acts as a backup for `colNames`. If `colNames` option is not defined then `label` option property gets utilized to assign column header.

**JSFiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/tfkanxhv/ refer to colNames and label values.